# Does BrowserRouter use more data/bandwidth than HashRouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rest, react-router

So I'm an iOS Developer who has been learning some React recently. I am now learning about routing. For now, I will be hosting my web app in the Firebase Hosting free tier, so the amount of bandwidth it uses is a real concern.

I need to decide if I should use a `BrowserRouter` or a `HashRouter`. As far as I know `BrowserRouter` is better, but in exchange you give away not supporting older browsers, which tbh I don't care about.

However, I have read that `BrowserRouter` makes GET requests each time the URL changes, and `HashRouter` does not.

**Does this mean that using `BrowserRouter` would drain my free Firebase Hosting bandwidth faster?**

My app will get information from Cloud Firestore to populate its UI. Are these GET requests from `BrowserRouter` make me waste my free operations in my database? This is also a concern for now.

I am using React v16.13.1, react-router-dom v5.2.0, CoreUI for React v3.0.1, and Typescript v3.7.5, if this is useful to you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I have read that BrowserRouter makes GET requests each time the URL changes, and HashRouter does not.

Hi! This isn't true. `BrowserRouter` disables the default behavior for the generated `<a href="..." />` tags in your HTML, as long as you're using the `Link` component.

Try this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {BrowserRouter, Link, Route} from "react-router-dom";

const PageOne = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Page One</h1>
            <Link to={"/pagetwo"}>Page 2</Link>
        </div>
    )
}

const PageTwo = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Page Two</h1>
            <Link to={"/"}> Page 1</Link>
        </div>
    )
}

const App = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route path={"/"} exact component={PageOne}/>
            <Route path={"/pagetwo"} component={PageTwo}/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.querySelector("#root")
)
```

Inspect your network traffic (usually F12 -> Network) and watch what happens!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I forgot to mark the answer, sorry I was new to SO hahaha.